# PHP and Java Script interaction handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a requirement where on clicking button, I need to show all the links captured. The java script code would be in a separate file `test.php`, and the links are captured in an additional file `links_generation.php`. The function 'getLinks()' has a conditional flow that if no of links is less than 5, it would display all the links, else it would display 5 links and additional text that "x more links are there".
Now, I have a requirement where on click of button, I would like to show all the links captured. I'm not sure how to capture this using javascript.

can someone pleaser help how to proceed with this.

```
function getLink($result,$currency,$lang) {

    foreach($result as $id => $data) {
        $num++;
        if($num <= 5) $list = $list.linkName(substr($id,3));
    }
    $list = substr($list, 0, -2);
    echo "<li>".$lang['pagelike1']." ".$lang['pagelike2'].": ";
    echo $list;
    if($num > 5) echo "...".$lang['and']." ".($num-5).$lang['other_ad'];
    echo "</li>";
}}
```

PS: the code is slightly modified,and pls be assured that this is working. I would need to incorporate the new functionality. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: it's better to put the js file in a *.js file

Comment: may i  know where should I put *.js file

Comment: put it somewhere in you public directory.. somewhere where you serve static files